Type Parameters from function parameters
I have a function omit which takes an object as a parameter and a list of fields to omit and returns an object without the specified properties.
function omit<T>(instance: T, ...fields: Array<keyof T>) {
  const output: any = {}
  for (const [property, value] of Object.entries(instance)) {
    if ((fields as string[]).includes(property)) continue
    output[property] = value
  }
  return output
}

I want to define the return type as Omit<T, fields> where the fields is determined by the arguments passed into the function. Is this possible? I feel like it may be breaking the type/value boundary but would love to be able to do this.

There is a built-in Omit utility type, you can leverage it:
function omit<T extends object, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, ...fields: K[]): Omit<T, K> {
  const result = { ...obj };
  for (const field of fields) {
    delete result[field];
  }
  return result as Omit<T, K>;
}

// Example usage:
interface Example {
  a: number;
  b: string;
  c: boolean;
}

const example: Example = { a: 1, b: 'test', c: true };
const newObj = omit(example, 'a', 'c'); // newObj will have type { b: string }
console.log(newObj);

